# Inline keyboard не отправляет ссылку с парамерами

Tags: php, url, telegram, бот

Вопрос такой: `Telegram bot` отправляет сообщение с кнопкой (с ссылкой на сайт). Если указан один параметр: `"site.ru/test.php?one=1"` - все работает, если более `"site.ru/test.php?one=1&two=1&three=1"`, то нет.

Вот скрипт вызывающий кнопку:

```
$url = 'site.ru/test.php?one=1&two=1&three=1';
$replyMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup = ['inline_keyboard' => [[array("text"=>"Перейти к оплате","url"=>$url)]] ,'resize_keyboard' => true]);]
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло: rawurldecode — Декодирование URL-кодированной строки
Надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится :)

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема, в telegram при формировании ссылки, она нормально выводилась в html и функционировала. Когда же ее значение я передавал ввиде строки, она обрезалась. Помогло использование другого типа декодирования rawurlencode.